# Moto G 2nd Generation - Mobile Data is not working after the upgrade to 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, mobile-data, motorola-moto-g2

MOTO G 2nd gen, Mobile data not working (India) post Android Upgrade to 5.0.2 from 4.4.4...any clue..

could be linked to improper upgrade and is there a way to restore ??

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark the answer as accepted, this removes the need to modify the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weirdly I inserted another sim into the 2nd slot(it has no service btw), and voila The excalamtion(!) mark is gone from the mobile network icon and Mobile data is back up. I just hope XDA doo take a look at this... And yes I had tried soft reset , factory reset, re inserting the sim and re registering , APN manual config etc etc..

Comment: Well, great that looks like you need to reinsert the SIM and SD card once you did the update ! Now you can mark your question as solved I would say.

Comment: I had actually reinserted the single sim alone but that dint work, when i reinserted the sim along with the sim in the other slot it worked. Another bug i notice is that you can independently turn off mobile data for one sim, turning it off for one turns it off overall(wonder if its just me).

Answer (score 1):

My issue has been solved, I have changed my sim slot it is working now.
Previously I was using slot-2 for my sim so it was not connected to the internet, now I changed it to slot-1 the exclamatory mark has disappeared and the internet is working now.

-Thanks